# How to use jwplayer with rest query?

Tags: java, javascript, rest, mime-types, jwplayer

I'm trying to involve JWPlayer to my web site. I tried to get my video file from server.
Here my javascript:

```
       <div id='player'></div>
       <script type='text/javascript'>
           jwplayer('player').setup({
               file: "http://localhost:8080/rest/course/getVideoStream",
               width: '100%',
               aspectratio: '16:9'
           });
       </script>
```

And here my rest:

```
@GET
@Path("/getVideoStream")
    @Produces("video/mp4")
public Response getVideoStream(){
    File file = new File(storagePath + "videos/courses/1.mp4");
    return Response.ok(file, "video/mp4").build();
}
```

It doesn`t work, but if i try to change field "file" with reference to video which in a folder with javascript, it works.

Comment: Not sure if this is supported. We haven't tested this. Do you have an example of where you have tried this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `http://localhost:8080/rest/course/getVideoStream` does serve valid mp4 file,
try add

```
type:'mp4'
```

after

```
 aspectratio: '16:9'
```

full code:

```
   jwplayer('player').setup({
           file: "http://localhost:8080/rest/course/getVideoStream",
           width: '100%',
           aspectratio: '16:9',
           type:'mp4'
       });
```